# Spring boot, mongo DB bean error for SRV host name

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea

This is the error showing:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-20T13:02:09.356+05:30 ERROR 22968 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at com.example.full.FullApplication.main(FullApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SRV host name '${env.MONGO_CLUSTER}' was provided that does not contain at least three parts. It must contain a hostname, domain name and a top level domain.
at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.(ClusterSettings.java:594) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.(ClusterSettings.java:50) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.build(ClusterSettings.java:370) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.(MongoClientSettings.java:957) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.(MongoClientSettings.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.build(MongoClientSettings.java:600) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoClientFactorySupport.createMongoClient(MongoClientFactorySupport.java:50) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration.mongo(MongoAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
... 23 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0

This is my pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.2
 

com.example
full
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
full
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>20</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spring project version 3.1.0 version or above and in the pom.xml file the spring-dotenv version is 4.0.0

In your application.properties file change the syntax should be `$(MONGO_****)` and not `$(env.MONGO_****)`

In your .env file mention the connection uri details

```
MONGO_DATABASE=""
MONGO_USER=""
MONGO_PASSWORD=""
MONGO_CLUSTER=""
```

In the application.properites file

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=${MONGO_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USER}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_CLUSTER}
```

I got the same error before making these changes and it was resolved. Hope it helps!